# Showing that elements in a finite group is odd and even

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let G be a finite group.
>
> Show that the number of elements x of G such that $x^{3}=e$ is odd.
>
> Show that the number of elements x of G such that $x^{2}\neq$ e is even

Looking for a useful **hint** to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e^3 = e$.

Next, note that if $x \neq e$ and $x^3 = e$ then also $(x^{-1})^3 = e$. We have $x \neq x^{-1}$ since otherwise we'd have $x^2 = e$ and therefore $x^3 = x \neq e$, a contradiction.

So: non-identity elements  $x$ such that  $x^3 = e$ come in pairs hence there is an even number of them. Plus the identity $e$ so in total there is an odd number of them.

To see that there is an even number of $x$ such that $x^2 \neq e$ note that if $x^2 \neq e$ then also $(x^{-1})^2 \neq e$ and $x \neq x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, Let $S=\{x\in G:x\neq x^{-1}\}$
Let $x\in S$. Then $x^{-1}\in S$

For the first part, let $T=\{x\in G:x^3=e\}$
Let $x\in T$.Then $x^3=e$.
Note that $(x^{-1})^3=(x^3)^{-1}=e$
Hence $x^{-1}\in T$

Comment: For the first part considering inverses also works, with a little wrinkle

Comment: @MarkBennet I know your idea already. Thanks!